# Have anybody worked on FLT considering a fourth integer apart from triplets?

Tags: pythagorean-triples

Most of the people concerned always discuss about only the three integers  to arrive a generalized form of the conjecture.; why so?

Answer (score 2):

It was only in 1987 that Noam Elkies solved this problem for the power $n=4$.  I don't think any solutions have been found for $n>4$ with three on the left-hand side.  This site has a lot of solutions with more than three numbers:  http://euler.free.fr/